# Limits question help me please?

Tags: limits

I have to find the limit of the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{(x+1)(x^2+2)...(x^n+n)}{[(nx)^n+1]^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}}$$

I tried to find the logarithm of the upper side and lower side but it didn't work..what shall I do?

Comment: Write down your expression here so we can read it, and it will be found when somebody comes by in 5 year's time would be a start. Look at the help for LaTeX imput (between `$` inline, between `$$` is display).

Answer (score 1):

If you square the expression (call it $a(x))$ you get
$$
a(x)^2=\frac{(x+1)^2(x^2+2)^2\cdot ...\cdot(x^n+n)^2}{(n^nx^n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{x^{n(n+1)}+\ldots +n!^2}{n^{n(n+1)}x^{n(n+1)}+\ldots + 1} 
$$
$a(x)^2$ is a fraction of two polynomials in $x$, so we only need to look at the leading coefficients to conclude the limit of $a(x)^2$ is $n^{-n(n+1)}$. So the limit of $a(x)$ is $n^{-n(n+1)/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the greatest power of each side. The answer is $0$.

Comment: Both numerator and denominator have $x^{n(n+1)/2}$, no?

Comment: Yes but not with the same coefficient ;)

Comment: No,the answer is 1/[1+(1/n)]...

Comment: Damien, the coefficients are constants --- no one is taking a limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x^{1+2+3+...+n}}{(nx)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$

Comment: I have thought about that,but it doesnt seem to tell me anything..

Comment: @Kyle92: As it seems that, $n$ is a fixed constant. And the powers of variable $x$ in den. and num. are the same.